# Django - Restricting ModelChoiceField to valid values

Tags: python, django, django-models

#### Models.py:

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    document = models.ForeignKey(Document)
    section = models.ForeignKey(Section, null=True, blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
```

#### Forms.py:

```
class CommentForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ('section', 'description')
```

Each Comment belongs to a Section of a Document. Each Document hasmany Sections. However, the ModelChoiceField printed out by Django will contain Sections for ALL Documents.

How do I tell Django to only print the Sections that belong to a particular Document?

I looked at [ModelFormSets - Changing the queryset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#changing-the-queryset) but I don't think it's quite what I'm after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to change the [ModelChoiceField's queryset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ModelChoiceField.queryset) and not the queryset of the formset.

Comment: The ModelForm class autogenerates the form from the model, ModelChoiceField would be for manually generated forms. I'm trying to stick to DRY principles, so perhaps I should look for a way to restrict it in the database.

Comment: Hm, but nontheless you should be able to modify the field's queryset. You could do something similar (filter the selectable sections by the document pk of your current instance) as in this snippet: http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/625

Answer (score 2):

If all you need to do is adjust the admin site you can override the [formfield_for_foreignkey](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.formfield_for_foreignkey) method on your django admin class.

From the docs:

> ModelAdmin.formfield_for_foreignkey(self,db_field, request, **kwargs)
>
> The formfield_for_foreignkey method on a ModelAdmin allows you to override the
>   default formfield for a foreign key field. For example, to return a subset
>   of objects for this foreign key field based on the user:

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
     def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
        if db_field.name == "car":
            kwargs["queryset"] = Car.objects.filter(owner=request.user)
        return super(MyModelAdmin, self).formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request, **kwargs)
```

> This uses the HttpRequest instance to filter the Car
>   foreign key field to only display the cars owned by the User instance.

Comment: Wouldn't that only be for the admin site, not for printing out a form on the frontend?